# How can I change the line color in pie chart

Tags: pgf-pie

I want to change the line color of a pie chart in LaTeX so that the line color of the slices take the fill color.

Mini example:

```
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[color={red, blue, yellow, green},
     sum=auto, after number=,text=pin,
     every only number node/.style={text=black}]{10/A,20/B,30/C,10/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This has a black line color. How can I change it to the fill color of the slice?

Comment: Instead of changing the line color, you should change the complete diagram: http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define a style for the lines (e.g. `lines/.style={draw=none}`) and then set the `style` key in `\pie` to `lines`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
     lines/.style={draw=none},
}
\pie[color={red, blue, yellow, green},
     sum=auto, after number=,text=pin,
     every only number node/.style={text=black},
     style={lines}
    ]{10/A,20/B,30/C,10/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Because of how the `style` key is handled internally, you have to define the `lines` style outside of the argument for `\pie` and you cannot put the style settings directly in the value of `style`.

Comment: All the slices aren't filled with blue, try `lines/.style={draw=\thecolor,thick}`. Edit: or perhaps just `draw=none`.

Comment: Ah I forgot that part of the question!!!